# How to check the key exist in list of dictionaries while unpacking

Tags: python, dictionary

I have sample data-set which is below.

While unpacking I got one key error

```
sample = [
  {
    "id": "100",
    "name": "Test",
    "Business": [
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Enterprise",
      },
      {
        "id": "307",
        "name": "Data",
      }]},
    {
    "id": "333",
    "name": "State",
    "Business": [
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Enterprise",
      },
      {
        "id": "307",
        "name": "Data",
      }],
       "System": [
      {
        "id": "235",
        "name": "Lake",
      }
    ],
    
    }    
]
```

Code is below

`x = [{**d, "Business": [i["name"] for i in d["Business"]]} for d in sample]`
x

In the second id=307 there is no "Business" so i got key error.  How to handle this

I need to add one condition in the code first check `Business` exist or not. Where i fit in the code?

Comment: Works for me, I don't get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `if "name of key" in name_of_dictionary.keys():` to check if a key exists or not.